# Working with Firebase and some Date filters

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have a hotel reservation app that shows a swipe-able calendar to the user. Now the end goal is to provide a calendar like interface with small dots below each date that is reserved. For now, I am just trying to print on the console all reservations between start date and end date (where start and end dates are start and end of months respectively).

However, I am unable to get this to work with Firebase. Here's how the data is on Firebase at the moment:

```
{
  "reservations" : {
    "-KSgRjwpssoZJWjV9ScM" : {
      "checkin" : 1474950600,
      "checkout" : 1475116200,
      "customer" : "-KMVMMudWJlFeiimtgJl"
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my Swift code to retrieve data:

```
private var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

// viewdidload:
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
ref.keepSynced(true)

// logic to fetch data
DispatchQueue.global().async {

        // Background Processing
        // Check Firebase for events between startdate and enddate
        print("Fetching Reservations")
        print(startDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        print(endDate.timeIntervalSince1970)

        self.ref.child("reservations").queryStarting(atValue: startDate.timeIntervalSince1970, childKey: "checkin").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

            print("Data Retrieved.\n")
            print(snapshot)

        })
}
```

Here's what gets printed onto the console right now:

```
Fetching Reservations
1469989800.0
1472581800.0
Fetching Reservations
1472668200.0
1475173800.0
```

As its clearly visible that the data falls within the second range but I still can't get it to show up.

What may be wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'v tried with this code and it worked:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let refReservations = ref.child("reservations")

let startDate: Double = 1472668200.0

refReservations
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "checkin")
  .queryStarting(atValue: startDate)
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    print(snap.value)
  }
```

The difference between your code and mine is I call one query more:

```
.queryOrdered(byChild: "checkin")
.queryStarting(atValue: startDate)
```

yours:

```
.queryStarting(atValue: startDate, childKey: "checkin")
```

Comment: The reason I use `.queryStarting(atValue: startDate, childKey: "checkin")` is because I need to load reservations based on month. So when the user swipes to a different month, I query firebase for reservations `starting at x date` and `ending at y date` - keys being `checkin` and `checkout`. So your suggested approach would give me bookings of, say September, in August too because of course the timestamp is greater (compared to `checkin`).

Comment: But adding to your answer, I got it to work by extending your query: `self.ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "checkin").queryStarting(atValue: startDate.timeIntervalSince1970).queryEnding(atValue: endDate.timeIntervalSince1970, childKey: "checkout").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
                print(snapshot)
                
            })`